# Sharing files between ubuntu 15.04 and android smartphone via wifi

Tags: wireless, files, android, sharing

I have ubuntu installed in my laptop and an android phone...is there any app like ShareIt , Superbeam , Xender (These softwares are used to transfer files via wifi between windows pc and android) available to use Ubuntu..So that we can transfer data between devices wirelessly

Comment: You can interact with your Android device via `adb`.  Typically, it's done over a USB cable, but you can enable it to work over the network.  You shouldn't leave your phone in a mode that makes `adb` available long-term, however, as that could be a security risk.  See [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) can be used to transfer files between devices easily.

[image]

Use the "Connect to PC option." Then visit http://web.xender.com/ and scan the QR code.

In case your phone or the PC does not have internet access, you can manually connect by using your browser by visiting the IP address mentioned in the App.

Comment: Juice SSH is solely an SSH client and does not  include scp support.

Comment: @paholg Thanks for pointing out, i've made the corrections

Comment: Totally works with android 6.0 and Mate 16.04 - even when failed with mtpfs jmptfs and various other techniques.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Airdroid (https://www.airdroid.com/) and connect your phone with pc. You can do more than just transfering files with it.
[Android App](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwito-jXtoDKAhWLBI4KHf0eBWAQFggwMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.sand.airdroid%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHr0SPha63WyseOvN5X9oZantC8KA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kdeconnect it's great app no only for sharing but to you can view notifications and other stuff..

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you want to transfer. I use Dropbox on Ubuntu, and Dropbox with DropSync on Android. I tired Kdeconnect, and it was not plug and play. I would have had to mess with ports, firewalls, etc. I *CAN* do that, but I prefer NOT to do that. I just set up a non public directory in either Ubuntu or Android and it gets reflected on both devices. I then push on the circling arrow emblem (push a poll request) using dropsync and it bypasses the sync cycle timer and causes instant sync. Drag and drop on ubuntu, and use a filemanager on Android to write them between source/destination directory on Android and the transfer directory in the Dropbox application. (Ubuntu has foreced all access to go through an abstraction that requires apps to create 'connectors', vs straight filesystem access. Basically, they are trying to force you to use Google products for cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Dukto. It's a good alternative to SHAREit. You need to install this tool on both devices Ubuntu and Android. Once installed, you can use the easily. Dukto makes it easy to transfer a large file in just minutes http://www.bettertechtips.com/ubuntu/transfer-files-ubuntu-android-wifi/

Comment: Please explain further how to use the program mentioned, dont just share the link

Comment: The link might get disappeared anytime. So, share the link only for reference or for more detail after you provide the complete answer

Comment: It's quite easy. Just install the Dukto app in both devices Ubuntu and Android at the same time. Your Android device will appear in the Dukto app in Ubuntu and vice versa. There is a menu to send files. But, be sure both devices are connected in the same wi-fi network

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a file transfer from your PC/Laptop(with a Linux distro) to Phone using following command:

1. In terminal go to the specific folder which contains the file to be sent to your phone.
2. Issue command:

   `python3 -m http.server`

   this will create a server with port 8000(Default port).
   If you want to use a different port issue the command:

   `python3 -m http.server 9999`

   this will create a server with port no 9999

   If you have python 2 then use:

   `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

   `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999`
3. In another terminal find your ip using the command `ifconfig`
4. In your phone go to url.

   `http://<your ip>:8000/`

   you can find all your file listed there.

Note, for this to work:

1. Both the phone and your system must be connected to same wifi access point or must be in same network.
2. Python 2.x or 3.x should be installed in your system. Python is there in most of the Linux distros by default.